# FK in table is not working while migrate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I create a migration for table at that time there is an issue with its through following error.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 1005 Can't create table `yourwebs_veridocedu`.`#sql-2c46_8e`
>   (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL:
>   alter table `user_role_mappings` add constraint
>   `user_role_mappings_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`)
>   references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Migration for userrolemapping table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_role_mappings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->integer('group_id');
            $table->integer('roleid');
            $table->integer('status');
            $table->integer('createdby');
            $table->integer('modifiedby');
            $table->string('publicguid');
            $table->string('privateguid');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('group_id')->references('id')->on('groups')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

Migration for Role table :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('userroles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('rolename');
         $table->integer('status')->default(1);
        $table->integer('createdby')->default(1);
        $table->integer('modifiedby')->default(1);
        $table->string('publicguid');
        $table->string('privateguid');
        $table->timestamps(); 

    });
}
```

Usertable migration:

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');


            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email',150)->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->integer('roleid')->unsigned();
            $table->rememberToken();

            /*Common Fields*/
            $table->integer('status');
            $table->integer('createdby');
            $table->integer('modifiedby');
            $table->string('publicguid');
            $table->string('privateguid');
            $table->timestamps();

           /*From other table */
            $table->foreign('roleid') ->references('id')->on('userroles')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

FK in table is not working which migrate.

Comment: Does `user_role_mappings` use the InnoDB engine?

Comment: No actually I have tried that one

Comment: It has to. Try `$table->engine = 'InnoDB';` and `$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir It works!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both tables have to use the `InnoDB` engine and the column types have to match:

```
Schema::create('user_role_mappings', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('group_id');
});
```

Comment: I have an issue with $table->foreign('course_code')->references('course_code')->on('scope_courses')->onDelete('cascade');

Comment: Same problem: `$table->unsignedInteger('group_id');`

Comment: Please post the `groups` migration.

Comment: I mean its diffrent table did you see that?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is the same: The column types have to match. `groups.id` is unsigned (I assume) while `user_role_mappings.group_id` is signed.

Answer (score 1):

`increments` columns are unsigned, your foreign key columns need to have the same signature. So you should change the columns like so:

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('group_id')->unsigned();
```

Comment: Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `yourwebs_veridocedu`.`#sql-2c46_ba` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_roleid_foreign` foreign key (`roleid`) references `userroles` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: The error is on your users table migration, but you didn't post that code here. It's possibly the same problem...

Comment: I have added users migration table

Answer (score 1):

Try something as given below.

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
$table->integer('group_id')->unsigned()->index();
```

Comment: I have a onDelete cluase

Comment: so what. you have onDelete clause

Comment: ok I got your point. Could you please let me know when there is string what should I do?

Comment: Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `yourwebs_veridocedu`.`#sql-2c46_ba` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_roleid_foreign` foreign key (`roleid`) references `userroles` (`id`) on delete cascade)